# How is this if condition working?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have Following IF statement and I can't figure out what it means:

```
if (data->tokens.size()) 
{..
  //reads each token in a for loop and assigns each token to a variable...
}
```

Tokens have six values in it so `tokens.size()` should return **6**, right?

I don't understand why we need an if condition there? From what i understand, if condition will be true if `tokens.size()` returns **1** and false if it returns **0**.

In my case, it returns **6**(or whatever the amount of tokens which can be any number and not just 0 or 1). So how is this if condition working?

In other words, I want to know how does if handle when it gets the values other than 0 and 1.

Comment: Nitpick: `if` is not a "loop".

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got the answer. And yes, if is not a loop but a conditional statement :)

Comment: May I suggest you change it to `if ( ! data->tokens.empty() ) {...}`. It is less confusing (and may be very slightly quicker in some cases, although that's not really a good reason here).

Comment: @BoBTFish *both* your reasons seem good here.  :)

Comment: @DrewDormann I disagree. Making the code clearer is a good reason (proof: this question exists), but there are very few cases where this would offer a performance improvement, and it would be so slight that it wouldn't be worth making the change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditional statemens in C and C++ are implicitly comparing with "not equal to zero" if nothing else is given. E.g. `if (data->tokens.size())` is the same as `if (data->tokens.size() != 0)`.

Comment: So it means if i have some tokens, then it accepts the if condition and only if tokens is empty will it not execute whatever is to be executed after that if statement?

Comment: If it's NOT empty (so if `size()` returns anything other than zero).

Answer (score 1):

`if` takes a true or false bool expression, not a number. Fortunately for us, if you give a number, it will be converted to a bool. False if the number is 0, true otherwise, so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a test of non-emptyness to ensure we don't iterate over an empty vector

Answer (score 0):

It is conditional not a loop. If it is true then you enter conditional block. If it's zero then it's false and it doesn't enter block. If there's any other value than 0 then it's true and it enters block.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data->tokens.size()) ~ if(data->tokens.size()!=0)
```

Comment: No, because if `size()` return -1 or -31212128317981, it is ALSO true. (from the context, it's impossible to say if `size()` returns a signed or unsigned value).

Comment: wouldn't it be nicer if it returned false for negatives?

Answer (score 0):

To make it more precise: the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) said:

> 6.4 Selection statements
>
> selection-statement:
>
> ```
> if ( condition ) statement
> ```
>
> … The rules for conditions apply both to selection-statements and to
>   the `for` and `while` statements (6.5). … The value of a condition that is
>   an initialized declaration in a statement other than a switch
>   statement is the value of the declared variable contextually converted
>   to `bool` (Clause 4). If that conversion is ill-formed, the program is
>   ill-formed.  … The value of a condition that is an expression is the
>   value of the expression, contextually **converted to `bool`;** if that
>   conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

Where conversion to bool mean:

> 4 Standard conversions
>
> Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to
>   a Boolean value. An expression `e` appearing in such a context is said
>   to be contextually converted to `bool` and is well-formed if and only if
>   **the declaration `bool t(e);`** is well-formed, for some invented temporary
>   variable t (8.5).

This is important. That is why you can do this sort of “magic”:

```
while(getline(cin,str))) cout<<str;
```

with will apply `bool(cin)`(in this case `getline` return `cin`))

In your example the conversion will be:

> 4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]
>
> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. For
>   direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

Just as an aside comment, chances are that the `if` in your example is almost useless or even just obfuscating the code. Consider:

```
for (int i=0; i< data->tokens.size(); ++i) 
{..
  //reads a token and assigns to a variable...
}
```

or:

```
for( const auto &token : data->tokens)
    {..
      // assigns token to a variable...
    }
```

In both case the the `for` will enter only if `size()>0` making redundant the `if`.